# Visual Studio event handlers being placed in unwanted positions in code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I place a control and then double click it to create the event handler, what controls the position in the cs file where the handler is placed? It's something that can become quite irritating with large files, where I may already have organised the placement of methods and events how I like it.

Recently, I've been working on a file and it puts these events up in the middle of the variables that I declare at the start of the file.